# How to make 2D coordinate transformation to the top left corner using Java?

Tags: java, math

How to make 2D coordinate transformation to the top left corner using Java?

I mean, normal 2D coordinate (X, Y) system starts in the lower left corner.

But in java 2D drawing start on top left corner.

I need a mathematical conversion to the top left corner.

If I want to color the pixel on `x = 83, y = 50;` in normal 2D system (start on lower left corner). - How can I transform to to drawing from top left corner?

I need some mathematics formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need some mathematic formula.

```
y = rowsCount - y - 1;
```

This formula changes `y` coordinate from lower-left to the top-left system